# How can I serve my root page from a CDN in Node.js / Express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

Suppose my root page ('/' path) is entirely static. I know that I can serve the page as static content to avoid the overhead of the rendering engine. However, suppose that I want to take it one step further and bypass Node.js entirely and serve it through a CDN (e.g. cdn.mydomain.com/index.html). How can I do this?

Comment: You could respond with just the document head and a script that loads the rest of the page from a cdn. If you redirect to the cdn, you have to make sure all your internal links point to the right domain.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible unless you want your users to have cdn.example.com in the URL bar instead of example.com. HTML pages should be send from the main domain, unless your site is entirely static in which case your should point your domain to the CDN.